# In Excel, is it possible to shift cells (row) of an entire table when first two columns are updated from another table?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a large table in Sheet1, and I'm trying to create a live copy of the first two columns to a table in Sheet2.

The table in Sheet2 also has other columns.

I'm trying to make it so that when a new row is inserted into the table in Sheet1, it will shift the entire row of the table in Sheet2, not just the live copy of the first two columns.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible! If you don't know VBA, now would be a good time to learn... Check out the Worksheet.Change event; you can use that to trigger an action when something is changed in your first sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have an idea of how I might go about starting this? I'm very new to VBA.

Comment: Learn to use VBA (you could start here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office), or find someone who uses it. People on this site will not write your code for you, but we can help if you get stuck.

Comment: If you want to do this manually, select all cells of the top row, then right-click insert to shift them down.

Comment: It sounds like you want to maintain (row) data integrity which IMO means a database and not excel. Having said that, if constraints demand you use excel, then I suggest you take a step back and ask yourself what you are really trying to accomplish as that may reduce VBA needs.